# Translation of Scala code section for a map method/function

Tags: scala, translate

Can someone translate this into something meaningful for me? (In the process learning Scala with a background of java/c/assembly):

```
broadcast(wireFormat.render(msg),selectedResources.map(_.resource).toSet.asJava).map(_ => msg)
```

I understand/get most of it, but there are two sections that are still a little fuzzy:
1) I'm assuming that map (*.resource) is operating upon the field [resource] for "Any"-thing that gets passed through it - is that correct?
2) What does the operation "* => msg" do in the last part of the statement?

TIA.

EDIT: For some reason the underscore character is not being rendered in the question #2, so it should read:

```
_ => msg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decode: `selectedResources.map(_.resource)` is equal to `selectedResources.map(x => x.resource)`(1). `_` is called a placeholder.  (1).toSet might be returning a Scala Set which is then converted to java.util.Set using `asJava`

`.map(_ => msg)` is nothing but `.map(x => msg)`. Basically you are not using any of the element. For example:

```
val msg = "hey"
scala> List(1,2,3).map(_ => hey)
res0: List[String] = List(hey,hey,hey)
```

Comment: Can you expand upon that last part for me? What I *think* is happening is that the placeholder is being used as an insertion-point for the results derived by the primary call itself (ie., broadcast) and into a function called "msg"  -- is that a correct assessment?